# How to define a controller inside a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I'm learning rails and got this small app for learning purposes.

This is my folder structure, I'm trying to customize it for a DDDish approach:

[image]

This is my launcher_controller:

```
module Web
    class LauncherController < ApplicationController
        def launch
            requestBody = params[:launcher]

            render json: requestBody
        end
    end
end
```

And the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    scope module: 'web' do
        post 'launcher/launch', action: 'launch', controller: 'launcher'
    end
end
```

I already added the web and controllers path to the autoload_paths for zeitwerk to load the files in application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << config.root.join('app', 'web')
config.autoload_paths << config.root.join('app', 'web', 'controllers')
```

I can fire rails server up but when I call the controller's action I get:

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Web)

I feel like this should be something really simple but I can't find the problem...
I'm following the docs at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

So what basic concept am I missing here? Am I not defining the module at the launch_controller.rb file?

**EDIT**

Ok, based on the first answern I changed the module to Web in the module definition and 'web' on the routes.rb.

Now I got

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Web)

I don't know if this could be a problem, but this is a web API only app.
I generated the project with the following command:

```
rails new tracker-launcher -M -O -J -T --api
```

Comment: In your file tree, you have `web` as the directory. But in the file you have `WebStuff` and in the routes you have `:web_stuff`. It can't find the correct director bc you named it differently

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Just updated the question with what you suggested. Even when the folder name and the module name match, I still get the same error.

Comment: I think you may also need to move the web directory inside the controllers directory and spearate the controllers there. And then if you need any other separation for your web scope, then create a directory in each main directory, ie models, services, etc.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Yeah, I'm getting to the same conclusion. Better not mess with rails base folders and do whatever namespacing you need inside them, for controllers at least. Other namespaces inside the folders I created inside the app folder works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for it. First thing I see is you defined `WebStuff`, but in routes using `webstuff`, which is `Webstuff` (see case). Try set it to `web_stuff` or rename classes/modules. Also, file names are important for [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Classic Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html) or [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Comment: The docs  example won't match the case of the module with that of the scope in the routes file.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

Comment: But I tried what you suggested anyway, if I match the module case, then rails can't find the folder web. I get the error:
'Web/launcher' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.